# Split a string and join the parts with a random order in Java

Tags: java, string, exception

Hi guys and ty for reading my question. I want to write a program which must read a String and split its words and join them by a random order again.I wrote this so far :

```
package read.java;
import java.io.*;       
public class ReadJava {
    public static int count;
    public static String[] stringsplit(String S)
    {
        count=0;
        String[] strings=new String[10];
        if (S.isEmpty())
            return strings;
        char start=0;
        while(true)
        {
            if(S.charAt(start)!=' ')
            {
                strings[count]+=S.charAt(start);
            }
            else
            {
                if(S.charAt(start)==' '&&S.charAt(start-1)!=' ')
                {
                    count++;
                }
                if(start==S.length())
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
           start++;

        }

        return strings;
    }

    public static String stringjoin(String[] words)
    {
        int [] wordnum= new int [count];
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            wordnum[i]=i;
        }
        String newS = new String();
        while (count!=0)
        {
            int randnum;
            randnum = (int)Math.random()%count;
            newS+=words[randnum];
            for(int i=randnum;i<count-2;i++)
            {
                wordnum[i]=wordnum[i+1];
            }
            count--;
        }
        return newS;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bfreader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String S = new String();
        S=bfreader.readLine();
        String[] strings=new String[10];
        strings=stringsplit(S);
        S=stringjoin(strings);
        System.out.println(S);
    }
}
```

But when I'm compiling and input any sentences it throws an exception :

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in this line :

```
S.charAt(start)!=' '
```

I'm new to Java and I don't have any ideas about the error.

---

That Error fixed by your helps but its still wrong. I fixed my while in stringsplit to this :

```
while(start < S.length())
```

but its printing "nullThisnullisnullanulltest" for "This is a test"
Is my stringjoin method wrong ?!

Comment: It means that the argument to charAt is outsde of the allowed range - either < 0 or >= the length of the String. Classical off-by-one error on your side.

Comment: What is the value of S? The exception is telling you that you are outside the length of S when trying to take a character, so it's likely you need to verify that start is not outside the length of the S.

Comment: For your convenience: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: I dont know why its printing something like this : nullfirstwordnullsecondwordnullthirdwordnull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `while` condition:

```
while (start < S.length())
```

Because the maximum index of the string you can reach is (length of string - 1, zero-based index)

P.S. you can delete the following from your split function, it will never be reached:

```
if(start==S.length())
    {
        count++;
        break;
    }
```

P.P.S. You are getting "null"s at the output, because you init your array with "null" values. To resolve that, add the following after your array init `Arrays.fill(strings,"")`. So, the correct code at the start of your `stringsplit` function will be like that:

```
count=0;
String[] strings=new String[S.length()]; //we don't know the number of words we get, but this number definitely no more that length of incoming string
Arrays.fill(strings, "");
if (S.isEmpty()){
     ....
```

Comment: its working ty! :) but i dont know why its printing something like this : nullfirstwordnullsecondwordnullthirdwordnull

Answer (score 1):

The out-of-bounds exception is because you're attempting to access an index of the string outside of its range (since String is essentially a character array).

On another note, might I recommend:

```
String orig = "Some string with spaces";
String[] split = orig.split(" ");
```

Comment: i want to check other characters like . or , in the next level so i need to check my string character by character ...

Answer (score 0):

`start` ends up being equal to the length of the string, but you have to keep in mind that the length of the string is 1 greater than the end element (because the `String` is a zero-based array).

Make the condition in the while loop something along the line of `while(start < S.length)`